# how to configure ApacheDSUserStoreManager as an external ldap userstore manager in wso2 identity server

Tags: apacheds, wso2-identity-server

I am new to wso2 and I am using wso2 Identity Server for authentication and authorization to my project. But I have a problem to configure ApacheDSUserStoreManager as an external ldap userstore manager in wso2 identity server. please can anyone provide me the right way to proceed. my configuration is as follow.

**configuration file is**

```
<UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ApacheDSUserStoreManager">
    <Property name="defaultRealmName">sample.com</Property>
    <Property name="kdcEnabled">false</Property>
    <Property name="ConnectionURL">ldap://localhost:10389</Property> 
    <Property name="ConnectionName">uid=rpurimitla,ou=manage,dc=sample,dc=com</Property>
    <Property name="ConnectionPassword">sample</Property>
    <Property name="passwordHashMethod">SHA</Property>
    <Property name="UserSearchBase">ou=manage,dc=sample,dc=com</Property>
    <Property name="UserEntryObjectClass">inetOrgPerson</Property>
    <Property name="UserNameAttribute">uid</Property>
    <Property name="isADLDSRole">true</Property>
    <Property name="userAccountControl">512</Property>
    <Property name="UserNameListFilter">(objectClass=user)</Property>
    <Property name="UserNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=user)(cn=?))</Property>
    <Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-]{3,30}$</Property>
    <Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\\S]{3,30}$</Property>
    <Property name="PasswordJavaScriptRegEx">^[\\S]{5,30}$</Property>
    <Property name="RolenameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\\S]{3,30}$</Property>
    <Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-]{3,30}$</Property>
    <Property name="ReadLDAPGroups">true</Property>
    <Property name="WriteLDAPGroups">true</Property>
    <Property name="EmptyRolesAllowed">true</Property>
    <Property name="GroupSearchBase">ou=manage,dc=sample,dc=com</Property>
    <Property name="GroupEntryObjectClass">group</Property>
    <Property name="GroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
    <Property name="MembershipAttribute">member</Property>
    <Property name="GroupNameListFilter">(objectcategory=group)</Property>
    <Property name="GroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=group)(cn=?))</Property>
    <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
    <Property name="Referral">follow</Property>
    <Property name="BackLinksEnabled">true</Property>
    </UserStoreManager>
```

## **this is the error am getting**

2013-07-26 17:57:47,781]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.AgentHolder} -  Agent created !
[2013-07-26 17:57:47,859]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.AgentDS} -  Successfully deployed Agent Client
[2013-07-26 17:57:48,000]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.iwa.ui.internal.Activator} -  Integrated Windows Authenticator enabled in the system
[2013-07-26 17:57:48,234]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ldap.server.DirectoryActivator} -  Embedded LDAP is disabled.
[2013-07-26 17:57:49,781] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm} -  **Cannot create org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ApacheDSUserStoreManager
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ApacheDSUserStoreManager
    at** org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:215)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:147)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:113)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:223)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.(DefaultRealmService.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.(DefaultRealmService.java:116)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:67)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

================================================================================

Comment: your question looks similar to this SO
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330883/wso2-identity-server-external-ldap-throws-object-class-for-oid-identityperson-do

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IS 4.0.0 or a later version ApacheDSUserStoreManager class has been removed from those releases. You need to change your configurations according to your version.

You need to un-comment the below section from your user-mgt.xml and change the configurations accordingly.

```
  <!--UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager">
        <Property name="ConnectionURL">ldap://localhost:10389</Property>
        <Property name="ConnectionName">uid=admin,ou=system</Property>
        <Property name="ConnectionPassword">secret</Property>
        <Property name="passwordHashMethod">PLAIN_TEXT</Property>
        <Property name="UserNameListFilter">(objectClass=person)</Property>
        <Property name="UserEntryObjectClass">inetOrgPerson</Property>
        <Property name="UserSearchBase">ou=system</Property>
        <Property name="UserNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=person)(uid=?))</Property>
        <Property name="UserNameAttribute">uid</Property>
        <Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\\S]{3,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="RolenameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\\S]{3,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="PasswordJavaScriptRegEx">^[\\S]{5,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="ReadLDAPGroups">true</Property>
        <Property name="WriteLDAPGroups">true</Property>
        <Property name="EmptyRolesAllowed">false</Property>
        <Property name="GroupSearchBase">ou=system</Property>
        <Property name="GroupNameListFilter">(objectClass=groupOfNames)</Property>
        <Property name="GroupEntryObjectClass">groupOfNames</Property>
        <Property name="GroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=?))</Property>
        <Property name="GroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
        <Property name="MembershipAttribute">member</Property>
        <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
        <Property name="ReplaceEscapeCharactersAtUserLogin">true</Property>
        <Property name="maxFailedLoginAttempt">0</Property>
    </UserStoreManager-->
```

There is a related issues in below link [1].

[1] [WSO2 Identity Server external LDAP throws OBJECT_CLASS for OID identityperson does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330883/wso2-identity-server-external-ldap-throws-object-class-for-oid-identityperson-do/19786544#19786544)

Hope this is helpful.