# external ldap client for wso2 Identity Server to authenticate external ldap users

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I configured external ldap in wso2 Identity Server successfully. I ran one sample program to authenticate users in embedded ldap successfully, But I am unable to authenticate users in external ldap. please anyone provide the way to authenticate external ldap users in wso2 Identity Server.

I searched in wso2 documentation and web, I can't find any API(like java API) and sample client program to connect and authenticate users in external ldap.

can anyone provide the way to proceed further it is urgent requirement for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ravi purimitla I would be interested if your environment is running
In my case it did not work using the IS 4.1.0 so I posted a question here:
[WSO2 Identity Server external LDAP throws OBJECT_CLASS for OID identityperson does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330883/wso2-identity-server-external-ldap-throws-object-class-for-oid-identityperson-do)
Did you had similar problems?

Comment: thanks for answering me, now I configured external ldap successfully and authentication of users is also done. But I have some clarification regarding embedded ldap in wso2 IS, Is it possible to create dn: dc=sample,dc=com (as that of the structure in external ldap dn:example.com, dn:sample,com)?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the IS [documentation on how to connect to external LDAP](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/IS410/Configuring+External+User+Stores) server .
If you have successfully connected to external store, then authentication will happen against that usertore..
What is the issue you faced  when you authenticate with the external LDAP user store? 
You can file a [bug report](https://wso2.org/jira)..

Comment: Thank you @Ratha, I successfully authenticate users in external ldap. But I have another problem is, to create user in external ldap user store. The sample program is create user in embedded ldap only. I want some sample program to create user in external Ldap.